# NaN ERROR iOS (NSUInteger vs. CGFloat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, nan

I pulled this code from a reputable tutorial, and I get a NaN error on the CGFloat instance *imageHeight when I run the application. However, if I change the type to NSUInteger, the app builds out just fine. Is there anyone who could potentially explain whats happening. I understand the NaN = Not A Number, but CGFloat should work fine as the data type.

### Crashes

```
CGFloat imageHeight = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
self.mediaImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds), imageHeight);<--NaN ERROR is thrown here
```

### Does Not Crash

```
NSUInteger imageHeight = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
self.mediaImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds), imageHeight);
```

### Full method body

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSUInteger imageHeight = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
    self.mediaImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds), imageHeight);

    CGSize sizeOfUsernameAndCaptionLabel = [self sizeOfString:self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.attributedText];
    self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.mediaImageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds), sizeOfUsernameAndCaptionLabel.height);

    CGSize sizeOfCommentLabel = [self sizeOfString:self.commentLabel.attributedText];
    self.commentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.frame), CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), sizeOfCommentLabel.height);

    // Hide the line between cells
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)/2.0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)/2.0);
}
```

Comment: Can you post values for `self.mediaItem.image.size.height`, `self.mediaItem.image.size.width` and `CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds)`? :)

Comment: @sloik The values change and are based on the size of the image passed in. Each contentView for each cell may or may not be different. In other words I don't really know.

Comment: I updated the question with the complete method body and definition.

Comment: Why would CGFloat be able to handle NaN?

Comment: But you get a crash right? So what are the values when you get a crash? :)

Comment: I meant that CGFloat is a floating point value. I didn't mean that it can handle the NaN. I was just thinking in comparison to NSUInteger we shouldn't have had any problems. In other words, CGFloat should be fine as the data type. I apologize I wasn't clear enough in my question. I'll have it updated in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only likely way that you could get a NaN there is by computing `0 / 0`, so I deduce that the `height` and `width` members of `self.mediaItem.image.size` are probably both zero. That is, `self.mediaImage.image.size` is probably `CGSizeZero`.

Note that if `self.mediaItem` is nil, or if `self.mediaItem.image` is nil, then `self.mediaItem.image.size` returns `CGSizeZero`. My guess is one of those is nil.

You can easily check this. Either put a breakpoint in `layoutSubviews`, or add an `NSLog` at the top of it:

```
NSLog(@"layoutSubviews: mediaItem=%p image=%p size=%@",
    self.mediaItem, self.mediaItem.image,
    NSStringFromCGSize(self.mediaItem.image.size));
```

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: Based on your advice, checking to see if (self.mediaItem != nil) also handles the problem when using type CGFloat.

Comment: The reason you weren't getting an error when using `NSUInteger` is because converting a `CGFloat` NaN to an integer gives zero.